# Is there another anime series aside Gundam which created real scale giant robots?

Tags: merchandise, gundam

I was taking a look at the amazing real scale Gundam projects in Youtube. They arent real merchandising today but everything makes one think someday in the future they will be extremely expensive merchandising for billionaries or millionaries depending on if they are just statues or the real moving ones

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Is there another anime series aside Gundam which created real scale giant robots?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could count Tetsujin 28-go, or Gigantor as it was known in the west.

[image]

This one was erected in Wakamatsu Park, Kobe, after the Great Hanshin Earthquake of 1995. The idea was to rejuvenate the area with tourism.

As far as I know, this is full-scale, at 18m (59ft) tall.

Comment: Here it was known as Ironman 28, which is the literal translation of tetsujin to English (tetsu = ron, jin = man) , ironically because here we speak Spanish. BTW, I just realized the name precedes american's Ironman (Tetsujin 28= 1958, american's Ironman = 1963)

Answer (score 4):

The Scopedog from AT Votoms stands about 14 feet tall, so several people have made 1:1 scale models over the years.

[image: Scopedog]

Comment: Neat! Makes me think someone might have also already made more small-sized robots like GitS Tachikoma 1:1s, since I've seen plans for 1:2s at least.

Answer (score 1):

Real scale mecha from the 80's 6 episode anime OVA of Starship Troopers

[image]